# Write data from a list if the adjacent cell contains certain string

Tags: string, list, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I need to update hundreds of cells, and that would be trivial automating, but I am not being able to make it work.

I have a list like the following:

[image: Source list]

And, in a different tab, a list I have to populate with values above (in B) based on the appearance of the twitter handle in other column.

[image: Data destination]

The names are within a long text string (all of them begin with @), and it is not possible to re-order the list based on those names. Also, there are more names than values, so some cells will remain blank.

Is there a way I can write a formula that writes the values of the first list into the second one if the name in column A in that row is contained within the adjacent string?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear on your setup or the nature of the data. What is the name of the source sheet? Are there headers in Row 1 of each sheet or not? Does the data begin in Row 2 of each sheet? Also, it would help if you could share a *realistic* sample of one "name" as it might appear in the first sheet, Col-A, and a *realistic* sample of the string it would match from Col-C of the second sheet. Every detail matters.

Comment: Very true! I edited the question trying to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: What is the name of the first tab/sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this sample formula (Same sheet was used):

```
=arrayformula(if(C2:C<>"",iferror(vlookup(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C,"\B\@\w+"),A2:B,2,false),""),""))
```

### What it does?

- Use array formula to loop column C values
- Extract the twitter name (string that starts with @) using [Regexextract()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en)
- Use the extracted @twittername as search key to get the connections value using [vlookup()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

### Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have access to the spreadsheet, I can't know for sure what the line-break character is within the Col-A cells of your second sheet. And using this line-break character is important, since Twitter handles may use some non-alphanumeric characters such as the underscore and others which are not included in such REGEX notation as `\w`. I'm assuming here that the line-break character is CHAR(10) from the ASCII chart.

I also don't know the name of your first sheet; so here, I've just written it as `Sheet1`. You'll need to replace that with your actual sheet name, remembering to place it in single quotes if it contains anything but alphanumeric characters (e.g., `'Data Sheet'`).

That said, delete everything from Col-B in your second sheet (including the header "Connections") and place the following formula in cell B1 of that second sheet):

`=ArrayFormula({"Connections"; IF(A2:A="",, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,CHAR(10),"~"),"@[^~]+"),Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)))})`